# How can I do something like "for char in string" in Vim script?

Tags: vim

I've come up with this, but is there simple way I'm missing?

```
for s:char in split(s:string, '.\zs\ze.')
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The canonical way is

```
for s:item in split(s:mylist, '\zs')
```